# Print/Save autoencoder generated features in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I have this autoencoder:

```
input_dim = Input(shape=(10,))
encoded1 = Dense(30, activation = 'relu')(input_dim)
encoded2 = Dense(20, activation = 'relu')(encoded1)
encoded3 = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(encoded2)
encoded4 = Dense(6, activation = 'relu')(encoded3)
decoded1 = Dense(10, activation = 'relu')(encoded4)
decoded2 = Dense(20, activation = 'relu')(decoded1)
decoded3 = Dense(30, activation = 'relu')(decoded2)
decoded4 = Dense(ncol, activation = 'sigmoid')(decoded3)
autoencoder = Model(input = input_dim, output = decoded4) 
autoencoder.compile(-...)
autoencoder.fit(...)
```

Now I would like print or save the features generate in encoded4.
Basically, starting from a huge dataset I would like to extract the features generated by autoencoder, after the training part, to obtain a restricted representation of my dataset.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by creating the "encoder" model:

```
encoder = Model(input = input_dim, output = encoded4)
```

This will use the same layers instances that you trained with the autoencoder and should be producing the feature if you use it in "inference mode" like `encoder.predict()`

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

So, basically, by creating an encoder like this:

```
 encoder = Model (input_dim,encoded4)
 encoded_input=Input(shape=(6,))
```

and then using:

```
 encoded_data=encoder.predict(data)
```

where the data within the `predict` function is the dataset, the output generate by

```
 print encoded_data
```

is the **restricted representation** of my dataset.

It is right?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the input shape for this encoder model be `input_dim = Input(shape=(10,))` ?